# Geopandas how to move plot

Tags: python, dictionary, data-visualization, visualization, geopandas

i read some shx file and make a geopandas.plot
And I have such problem the part of the map are on the left side, how to move the plot to the center?

[image: geopandas.plot output]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind losing the edge, you could always reorient the axis.

```
plt.xmlim(0, 2.5)
```

However, you probably want the entire map.  Can you provide any more context such as the where you go the data or any code?

Comment: I have shape file from this [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/47813bc6ee3cea307fd904aa17ba31f120200715195821/332185). and use this code ` russia = geopandas.read_file('admin_level_4.shx', encoding='cp1251')
russia.plot(figsize = (15,15))`

Comment: and i just need this plot to be on the center of the picture, not devided on the right side